# Exit a shell script immediately with subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I have a while loop in a shell command:
`sp = subprocess.Popen("while [ 1 ]; do say \"hello world\"; done;")`.
However, when I send `sp.kill()`, the loop does not terminate immediately. Rather, it finishes the iteration it is on and then exits. I notice that the version without the loop, `"say \"hello world\"`, *will* terminate immediately. I've tried sending the various C codes using `signal`, but nothing seems to work. How can I immediately exit from the loop?

Comment: Some (most?) shells are optimized so that if the shell script is a single command, the shell uses `exec` to "step out" of the way, so that `Popen('say "hello world"', shell=True)` ends up behaving the same as `Popen(['say', 'hello world'])`.

Comment: Once you add the loop, the shell remains, because it has to execute the loop. As a result, the shell, not `say`, receives the signal.

Comment: The problem is that `say` is a child process, and if you don't signal it, then it doesn't matter what you do to its parent. You can create a process group and signal all the constituent processes if you want them all to die

Comment: I would try to avoid running arbitrary shell code using `Popen`. For example, in this case, you could simply implement the loop in Python, terminating the loop under the same condition in which you would call `sp.kill()`.

Comment: As I said, I figured it was part of the while loop. How should I implement a shell command that loops indefinitely but terminates immediately, then?

Comment: Signal the shell's process group, not only the shell. thatotherguy has already suggested it above.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I think I've figured something out after taking @chepner's advice— now I have a separate Python script responsible for handling the text-to-speech that has a thread responsible for reacting to a termination signal, which is ideal. I also chose this because I thought setting a process group was impossible on Windows, and also because I couldn't find any good documentation on creating process groups. Thanks for the help, I'll keep all your advice in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is killing the process using `kill` command with `-9` option for sending `SIGKILL` signal. This doesn't let the process to handle the signal and it terminates it entirely. There are other ways for sending this signal. Like `os.kill()`

You just need to figure out what is the UID of the process and then kill it.